# Mind-muscle cues for hips flexion without tilting the pelvis

Tags: weightlifting, workout, legs, lower-back

I need some cues about how to flex the hips (for instance in deadlift, squat or to get into the starting position of barbell row) without causing anterior or posterior pelvic tilt.

Of course bracing the core (by squeezing both the abs and the lumbar extensors) is a good way to keep the pelvis neutral. However, I think I need to have a clear idea of what kind of movement hip flexion is and hence of what I should think whilst performing it.

From what I can gather, hips flexion is something like the following picture.

[image]

**Questions**:

1. **It seems to me that it wants the pelvis be pushed backwards and the upper body forwards.** It occurs because the ileopsoas shortens and the glute lengthens. Is it a correct interpretation?
2. **It may happen to posteriorly tilt the pelvis whist trying to flex the hips**, like in the following picture. I'd say that the cause may be not engaging the hip flexors (ileopsoas) and hence trying to flex the torso by rounding the upper back. Is it a correct interpretation? If it is, the solution is simply to engage the hip flexors.

[image]

3. The hip flexors (ileopsoas) can anteriorly tilt the pelvis. Hence, **how can we engage the ileopsoas in order to perform hip flexion instead of anteriorly tilting the pelvis?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say your assessment is correct. There are a couple of cues that you may find useful. One is the "waiter's bow", with one hand placed on your navel to help push your hips back as you bend forwards. Alternatively you can place your fingers into the crease at the front of your hips, and think about "folding" your body at this point.

Some awareness of your spinal position is beneficial, for this I would recommend the "cat-camel" exercise, doing several repetitions of each and then coming back to a neutral position. If you can get a good feeling for what a neutral spine feels like, then you can apply this to hip flexion, trying to maintain a neutral spine position throughout. If you find that difficult, another possibility is to get someone to apply some strapping tape to your spinal erectors with your spine in a neutral position. Then, if you start to flex your spine during hip flexion, you will immediately feel a pull on your skin from the tape.